# Is there an entry point in Ruby code execution to be used by a Ruby profiler?

Tags: ruby, profiling

I have a Java profiler which is a JavaAgent which does BCI on my classes and reports the statistics.

I was trying to create a basic profiler for Ruby as well (just for learning). I was wondering is there a similar mechanism for Ruby as well where I can provide a profiler class to be executed when I start my standalone Ruby program and it starts reporting statistics for the program.

I can search for getting statistics from Ruby however currently my concern is how to invoke the profiler class before execution begins for my code. Note that in case of JavaAgent, no source files needed to be modified as the byte code was directly instrumented instead of source files.

I expect a similar solution for Ruby as well, so that I dont need to modify my source files. In case my approach itself is wrong, is there any guideline or approach that I should follow for creating my basic profiler would be really helpful.

How can I cause my profiler class to be invoked before Ruby begins executing the code being profiled?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: @screenmutt how to invoke the profiler class before execution begins for my code ?

Comment: https://github.com/ruby-prof/ruby-prof

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.newrelic.com/ruby is really good, and there is a developer mode, you can take a look: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/ruby/developer-mode

Comment: I am going to accept this as answer as I got a fair bit of idea going through the docs and pages mentioned in the links . Although Screenmutt's answer also seem appropriate and I obtained a fair bit of good information from what he had suggested , the accepted answer was first to shed a light on what I was interested in knowing .